# Formula to highlight all cells within 6 business days in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to create a rule in conditional formatting to highlight all dates that are within 6 business days.

The best I could come up with is `=AND(L1>TODAY(),L1<=(TODAY()+6))`.  The problem with this formula is that it includes weekend dates.  I want a formula that counts dates that are only weekdays.

What formula do I use?

Comment: you want `WORKDAY`. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33

Comment: Hey @Anonymous,, you mean to say that you want to highlight all weekdays for the month except Weekend or except Weekends & Holidays !!